# Structural induction over list

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, lists

I want to prove that `unique(reverse(L)) = reverse(unique(L))` where L is a List.

List has the following constructors:
`[] : -> List`
`[e] : Element -> List`
`cons(e, L) : Element x List -> List`

I defined unique and reverse as follows:
`unique : List -> List`
`reverse : List -> List`

`unique([]) = []`
`unique([e]) = [e]`
`unique(cons(e, L)) = cons(e, unique(L)), if member(e, L) = false`
`unique(cons(e, L)) = unique(L), if member(e, L) = true`

`reverse([]) = []`
`reverse([e]) = [e]`
`reverse(cons(e, L)) = append(reverse(L), [e])`

also,
`member : Element x List -> {true, false}`
`member(e, []) = false`
`member(e, [a]) = (e == a)` (true, if a is equal to e; false, if a isn't equal to e)
`member(e, cons(a, L)) = (e == a) V member(e, L)` (V is logical disjunction)

`append : List x List -> List`
`append([], L) = L`
`append([e], L) = cons(e, L)`
`append(cons(e, L1), L2) = cons(e, append(L1, L2))`

Both base cases are easy to verify.

**Induction hypothesis:** I assume `unique(reverse(L)) = reverse(unique(L))` is true

**Inductive step:** I have to prove that `unique(reverse(cons(e, L))) = reverse(unique(cons(e, L)))` is true

I consider two cases:

1. `member(e, L) = true`, then:

   `unique(reverse(cons(e, L))) = unique(append(reverse(L), [e]))`

   `reverse(unique(cons(e, L))) = reverse(unique(L)) = unique(reverse(L))`

   Those are obviously true, but I don't know how to formally prove it (I can explain it in words, but that's not the point).
2. `member(e, L) = false`, then:

   `unique(reverse(cons(e, L))) = unique(append(reverse(L, [e])))`

   `reverse(unique(cons(e, L))) = reverse(cons(e, unique(L))) = append(reverse(unique(L)), [e]) = append(unique(reverse(L)), [e])`

   I'm stucked here.

unique, reverse, append and member don't have to be defined that way, but they have to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure that what you're trying to prove is right.

```
unique [] = []
unique (x : xs) = if x `in` xs then unique xs else x : unique xs

reverse [] = []
reverse (x : xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]
```

If we take xs = [a, b, a, c] then:

```
unique [a, b, a, c]
= { unique.2 }
if a `in` [b, a, c] then unique [b, a, c] else a : unique [b, a, c]
= { ... }
[b, a, c]

reverse [b, a, c] = [c, a, b]

reverse [a, b, a, c] = [c, a, b, a]

unique [c, a, b, a]
= { unique.2 }
c : unique [a, b, a]
= { unique . 2 }
c : [b, a]
= [c, b, a]
```

Hence, unique (reverse [a, b, a, c]) = [c, b, a] and reverse (unique [a, b, a, c]) = [c, a, b].

Comment: Well spotted!  Welcome to [cs.se].